# Differences between -O0 and -O1 in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm

While compiling some code I noticed big differences in the assembler created between -O0 and -O1. I wanted to run through enabling/disabling optimisations until I found out what was causing a certain change in the assembler.

If I use -fverbose-asm to find out exactly which flags O1 is enabling compared to O0, and then disable them manually, why is the assembler produced still so massively different? Even if I run gcc with O0 and manually add all the flags that fverbose-asm said were enabled with O1, I don't get the same assembler that I would have got just by using O1.

Is there anything apart from '-f...' and '-m...' that can be changed?

Or is is just that 'O1' has some magic compared with 'O0' that cannot be turned off.

---

Sorry for the crypticness - this was related to [Reducing stack usage during recursion with GCC + ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155421/reducing-stack-usage-during-recursion-with-gcc-arm) however the mention of it was making the question a bit hard to understand.

Comment: So the problem is that you don't know the name (or killer combination) of the "offending optimization" that increases stack use, and you *also* don't know the names of the optimizations from `-Os` that you need? Where "don't know the name" includes the possibility that they don't have names at all, they're miscellaneous extra optimizations enabled by `O1` or `Os` that can't be controlled individually.

Comment: Yes - basically I know all the flags that GCC says it has enabled (via -fverbose-asm). However disabling them manually doesn't fix the problem, so it must be some 'magic' that I am unable to control.

HOWEVER I have just discovered (see linked question) that the problem still existed with O0, just in a different way. It would still be good to know if there is an answer to this question though - as it is scary not being able to control the optimisations.

Comment: Did you tried use GCC's `attribute(())` or rewrite a function in another way (e. g. made variables static or allocate their space manually)? As the last-chance solution problematic function can be rewritten in assembly.

Comment: Are you sure it's an optimisation? Did you look at the assembler output even in the -O0 case? I'm pretty sure gcc always generates code like this since it's the simplest way to generate code. I don't have an arm gcc right now to verify, but this is something that would probably be handled in machine independent parts of the compiler anyway.

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the question to try and make it clearer (and distinct from the other issue), sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 10):

If all you want is to see which passes are enabled at O1 which are not enabled at O0 you could run something like:

```
gcc -O0 test.c -fdump-tree-all -da
ls > O0
rm -f test.c.*
gcc -O1 test.c -fdump-tree-all -da
ls > O1
diff O0 O1
```

A similar process, using the set of flags which you discovered, will let you see what extra magic passes not controlled by flags are undertaken by GCC at O1.

EDIT:

A less messy way might be to compare the output of -fdump-passes, which will list which passes are ON or OFF to stderr.

So something like:

```
gcc -O0 test.c -fdump-passes |& grep ON > O0
gcc -O1 test.c -fdump-passes |& grep ON > O1
diff O0 O1
```

Answer (score 4):

Not that this helps, other than providing some evidence for your suspicions about `-O1` magic that can't be turned off:

- From http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-11/msg00214.html:

  > CAVEAT, not all optimizations enabled by -O1 have a command-line toggle flag to disable them.
- From Hagen's "Definitive Guide to GCC, 2nd Ed":

  > Note: Not all of GCC’s optimizations can be controlled using a flag. GCC performs some optimizations automatically and, short of modifying the source code, you cannot disable these optimizations when you request optimization using -O

Unfortunately, I haven't found any clear statement about what these hard-coded optimizations might be. Hopefully someone who is knowlegable about GCC's internals might post an answer with some information about that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many options you can also change parameters, e.g.

```
--param max-crossjump-edges=1
```

which affects the code generation. Check the source file `params.def` for all available params.

But there is no way to switch from -O0 to -O1, or from -O1 to -O2, or from -Os or to -Os or etc. p.p. , by adding options, without patching the source code, since there are several hard coded locations where the level is checked without consulting an command line option, e.g.:

```
  return perform_tree_ssa_dce (/*aggressive=*/optimize >= 2);
```